# Preencher option com dados do Flask - Front x Backend

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, front-end, back-end

Tenho pouco conhecimento em frontend e estou com precisando fazer o seguinte:

No meu Backend tenho uma função ao qual executo em python e que retorna uma lista conforme print.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def info():
    return 'Navegar para os dados'

@app.route('/Teste')
def mensagem():
    fd='var_fd'
    dt='var_dt'

    _engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("minha_string_de_conexao")
    sql = """
    select data 
        from minha_tabela
    where codigo like '%{0}%'
    and data={1!r}
    order by 1 desc; 
    """.format(fd, dt)

    pos = pd.read_sql_query(sql,_engine)

    value = str(pos.iloc[0:]['data'].tolist())
    return str(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image: tela do navegador]

```
<div class="col-md-12" align="right" style="font-size:12px;color:black;margin-left:10ox;margin-bottom:15px;">
    <select class="form-control" style="width:120px">
    <option selected value="">hh:mm:ss</option>
</div>
```

Preciso que o retorno desses dados seja populado na combobox. Acredito que com jquery seja uma boa opção, no entanto, não estou conseguindo realizar essa demanda.

Como mencionei inicialmente, não tenho grande conhecimento em front. Grato!

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar um AJAX simples com jQuery. Coloque um `id` no `select` para ter uma referência:

```
<select id="horas" class="form-control" style="width:120px">
   <option selected value="">hh:mm:ss</option>
</select>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

       $.get("http://127.0.0.1/Teste", function(data){

          var opts = '';

          $.each(data, function(i, v){

             opts += '<option value="'+ v +'">'+ v +'</option>';

          });

          $("#horas").append(opts);

       }, "json");

    });

</script>
```

Como o retorno virá uma array em forma de string, a opção `"json"` irá converter a string em array.

Comment: Muito obrigado por seu retorno. Acabei ficando com uma dúvida. Em qual momento o AJAX chama a função que está no Python? Eu devo adaptar o código que você me enviou?

Comment: Aqui: `$.get("http://127.0.0.1/Teste", function(data){`, a primeira informação entre aspas é a URL de onde virá o retorno do back-end, ou seja. `http://127.0.0.1/Teste`.

Comment: Eu não entendo de Phyton, mas no arquivo onde é gerado a array que vc mostrou no print, você deve retornar essa array para o AJAX... No PHP seria um `echo`.

Comment: Como o AJAX é uma requisição HTTP, é como se vc fizesse um arquivo em Phyton que imprimisse na tela apenas essa array, e o AJAX irá puxar ela em forma de string.

Comment: Perfeito Sam. Pelo que entendi, a etapa que você me explicou "pega" os dados da URL que representa o retorno do back-end. No entanto, para que essa URL seja gerada, eu preciso chamar a função no Python que no caso é a def mensagem().

Comment: Isso. Basicamente vc deve gerar um retorno para o AJAX, algo que gere uma string. Acho que no Phyton seria um tipo de `print()`.

Comment: Pelo que vejo, a função do seu Phyton tem um return... vc deveria imprimir esse retorno para que o AJAX o receba.

Comment: Procure marcar ✔️ na resposta das suas perguntas que resolveu a questão. Estava olhando seu histórico de perguntas e vi que nenhuma foi finalizada com ✔️. O esforço dos usuários em responder perguntas é recompensado quando vc marca ✔️ na melhor resposta ou vota positivo nas que vc achou útil. Abs!